# Button or link to slide content to be visible?

Tags: buttons, hyperlinks, content, product

Should I use a button or a text link to trigger a downward slide with content section on ecommerce shop's product page?

**Update**: The opening content should display next to the product image just above short product description. It would be about part payment options and it is not needed by all customers, but still important.

I would assume that button would be preferred solution as it is kind of an action. Link would suggest other kind of behaviour.

However now I think that accordion might work also. Just the text row and maybe a plus icon.

Comment: With current information provided your question doesn't have a right answer, you could use either of them. Do you need to bring more attention to the content? How much content is there? If there's a lot of content, maybe you should divide it into sections and use accordion? If there isn't a lot of content, why do you want to hide the content by default?

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, buttons and links are both CTA's, but they communicate 2 different things. A rule of thumb for this question: [**link takes user to a new location, a button changes the state of the website/application**](https://www.washington.edu/accesstech/websites/links-buttons/). In your case the solution would be to simply put a button that would collapse on click and provide user with more information.